# HAProxy close front-end connection after N HTTP requests

Tags: haproxy

I'm attempting to configure HAProxy to close a client TCP connection after it has been used to process N requests. My goal is to have our long-lived clients occasionally re-establish connections that are otherwise kept-alive by HTTP Keep-Alive.

Basically I'm trying to implement the equivalent of nginx's keepalive_requests (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#keepalive_requests).

I currently have something like:

```
frontend https-in
  bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem

  stick-table type binary len 32 size 1000 expire 75s store gpc0

  acl close_connection sc0_get_gpc0 gt 3
  acl exceeded_connection sc0_get_gpc0 gt 4

  http-response set-header Connection Keep-Alive unless close_connection
  http-response set-header Keep-Alive timeout=75\ max=3 unless close_connection
  http-response set-header Connection Close if close_connection
  timeout http-keep-alive 75s
  timeout client 75s

  tcp-request content track-sc0 ssl_fc_session_id
  tcp-request content reject if exceeded_connection

  http-request sc-inc-gpc0

  default_backend https

backend https
  option httpchk GET /health

  server localhost 127.0.0.1:8080 maxconn 1000
```

But some problems with this include:

- The SSL session ID may be re-used across connections
- This ends abruptly closing a connection from a client when they've exceeded the threshold (assuming they ignore the `Connection: Close`)

Are there any recommended approaches for something like this? Ideally I would like to:

- Track the counter based on individual TCP connection (not `src` to avoid the case where the same IP has multiple connections established)
- Close the connection on the final response (at the same time I send `Connection: Close`)

But I haven't been able to track down ways to do either of those.

Thanks!

**Edit**

I was able to devise a better way to track unique TCP connections by creating hashing a tuple of the src,src_port,dst,dst_port:

```
  http-request set-header X-Unique-Id %[src]:%[src_port]:%[dst]:%[dst_port]
  http-request set-header X-Unique-Id-SHA %[req.fhdr(X-Unique-Id),sha1]
  http-request track-sc0 req.fhdr(X-Unique-Id-SHA)
```

I'm not crazy about having to create the dummy headers, but this seems to work.

Comment: For cases, where Connection: Close is ignored, you could use ForceClose (https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.7/configuration.html#option%20forceclose).

Comment: @Tobi I can, but I only want to close the connection after so many requests. `option forceclose` will cause it to forcibly close after _every_ request (as I understand it).

Comment: You can track on the source port, unless you have a huge traffic there is a little chance that two clients will use the same port at the same time.

Comment: @MoEmEn We have about ~6k active connections at any given time. I think this means, even using the maximum port range (65535 - 1024), that there is an almost certain probability that two of them will share the same source port (using the formula from the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem): [1 - (64511! / ((64511 ^ 6000) * (64511 - 6000)!))](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+-+(64511!+%2F+((64511+%5E+6000)+*+(64511+-+6000)!)))).

Comment: I edited the post to add an approach that I came up with, hashing a concatenation of the src/src_port/dst/dist_port. It works, but I'd still like to eliminate the need to calculate the intermediate values if I can find a fetch value that is unique to the connection.